# can l use ngIf condition to change mean of word?

Tags: angular, ionic4

l am a beginner in angular and ionic. l am trying to get data as JSON from URL and I want to change the meaning of word coming from URL to another language. I tried with ngif to serve the purpose, but it didn't work!

what l did to change the meaning

```
<td text-right *ngIf="item?.flight.status.generic.status.text == 'scheduled';">مجدولة</td>
```

Even sometimes l got `null`  value from URL, I need to check it with ngif

```
<td text-right *ngIf="!item.flight.status.generic.status.text == 'null';">N/A</td>
```

at same time I use ngfor to loop over the data:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" routerDirection="forward" > 
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr >
              <td text-right *ngIf="item?.flight.status.generic.status.text == 'scheduled';">مجدولة</td>
              <td text-right *ngIf="!item.flight.status.generic.status.text == 'null';">N/A</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: You don't need two `ngIf` - you can do the same thing with `<td text-right>{{item?.flight.status.generic.status.text == "scheduled" ? "Scheduled" : "N/A"}}`

Comment: even multiple value ? l mean like that {{item?.flight.status.generic.status.text == "scheduled" ? == "canceled "?  " الغيت " "Scheduled" : "N/A"}}

Comment: You can add as many operators as you want in the ternary - once you get past a few though you really should extract to either a component function or, if you need to go through a ton of logic, use a pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an angular PIPE. That is what pipes are used for. So certain value gets mapped/translated .. to desired value by some logic.
Check this: [angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

You can easily create your own pipe, as is described here: [custom angular pipe](https://toddmotto.com/angular-pipes-custom-pipes)

So your would use something like this:

```
<td text-right>{{item?.flight.status.generic.status.text | myPipe}}</td>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would like some reason i was downvoted next time. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid approach. It may be too much overhead for a simple condition like the question shows, but as more logic is required to transform the text the more a pipe makes sense.

Comment: @NathanBeck Yeah its more overhead and its not always necessary to complicate (my colleagues always say I complicate :D). But with my exp as application grows its easier for me to keep concerns separated. In my HTML I just keep directives/classes/... and let the component handle the logic when to show/hide things. Lets say *ngIf="isValid". Where isValid is a getter inside component containing complex logic. Also I let services to provide/manipulate data. And pipes to transform some values.
Im not saying this is the best way. This just helped me keep my sanity at larger projects I worked on.

Comment: Sure -- there are indeed several good approaches for this kind of thing. I really just don't like seeing valid approaches downvoted for no reason.